# NULLIF how to set it properly in this query

Tags: db2, tablespace, nullif

I am using the following query to get some tablespaces usage at a glance:

```
db2 "select substr(tbsp_name,1,30) as Tablespace_Name, tbsp_type as Type, substr(tbsp_state,1,20) as Status, (tbsp_total_size_kb / 1024 ) as Size_Meg, smallint((float(tbsp_free_size_kb)/ float(tbsp_total_size_kb))*100) as Percent_Free_Space, int((tbsp_free_size_kb) / 1024 )as Meg_Free_Space from sysibmadm.tbsp_utilization where smallint((float(tbsp_free_size_kb)/ float(tbsp_total_size_kb))*100) < 20 order by Percent_Free_Space"
```

however, I'm stuck with the following error:

> SQL0801N  Division by zero was attempted.  SQLSTATE=22012

I understand you can fix this error with a `NULLIF` however I can't find the correct way to set in in the query, thanks for the help.

( using "DB2 v9.7.0.11", "s150922", "IP23937", and Fix Pack
"11")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use case:

```
CASE WHEN tbsp_total_size_kb=0 THEN NULL ELSE (tbsp_total_size_kb / 1024 ) END as Size_Meg
```

if `tbsp_total_size_kb` can be null IFNULL like this:

```
CASE WHEN IFNULL(tbsp_total_size_kb,0)=0 THEN NULL ELSE (tbsp_total_size_kb / 1024 ) END as Size_Meg
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment brother, how would it be the complete query with this modification? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> smallint(float(tbsp_free_size_kb) / float(**nullif(tbsp_total_size_kb,
>   0)**) * 100)